# How to use incontains for filtering by using foreignkey in django?

Tags: python, django

I have models

```
SiswaID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
WaliKelasID = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
SiswaKelas = models.ForeignKey(biayapendidikan, null=True, blank=True)

class biayapendidikan(models.Model):
     BiayaID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     BiayaSpp=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
     BiayaDpps=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
     Kelas=models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
     Unit=models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
     BiayaKeterangan=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Kelas
```

and i want to filtering i it in template by SiswaKelas(ForeignKey)

```
keyword2=request.GET['tingkat']
siswa['listsiswa'] = DataPribadiSiswa.objects.filter(Q(SiswaKelas__icontains = keyword2))
return render(request, 'index.html', siswa)
```

when i run it, i get this error

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. Model attributes should be lowercased and `_` underscore separated.

Secondly. If you wanna use the case-insensitive containment test `icontains` on foreign keys, you need to supply the attribute you wanna filter by too.

And lastly, you don't need to use `Q` object here.

In your case it would be:

```
DataPribadiSiswa.objects.filter(siswa_kelas__some_name__icontains=keyword2))
```

Comment: Show `biayapendidikan`.

Comment: i have add biayapendidikan model to my question

Comment: Then in your case it will be: `DataPribadiSiswa.objects.filter(SiswaKelas__ Kelas__icontains=keyword2))`

Comment: Again, you need to follow naming conventions, cause I believe at some point it will not work with the way ORM is designed. Model names should be `CamelCased`, model attributes should be `lowercase_underscored`. Here's the link you should read for sure https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Allright, Thank you @Andrey its workign now. And thank you for your sugestion

Comment: No worries. Good luck.